# How to use ids in file paths?

Tags: html

I have seen that many websites use ids in file paths like so:
https://example.com/name#id/example
like in https://alexa.amazon.com/spa/index.html#skills/?ref-suffix=nav_nav
I can't understand how to use that
please help

Comment: the ids is may be the item id or what every site have inside him.
you want to control it in the html?

Comment: You mean the ```#skills``` ?